# Shouldn't standard specializations of std::atomic lack value constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate, language-lawyer, atomic

The general version of the `std::atomic` template has a value constructor declared as

`constexpr atomic( T desired );` (See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic))

It is also said that `bool`, integral and pointer specializations of the template have (quoted from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic))

> standard layout, trivial default constructors, and trivial
>   destructors. They support aggregate initialization syntax.

This makes sense, for classes having only trivial default ctor and dtor (i.e., without a value ctor) qualifies as an aggregate and hence supports aggregate initialization syntax. However, the following code compiles fine on both GCC and clang:

`std::atomic_int i(9);`

This implies that a value ctor should exist. Is this a violation of the standard?

Quoted from C++11 standard

> These specializations shall have standard layout, trivial default
>   constructors, and trivial destructors. They shall each support
>   aggregate initialization syntax.

This does not make it clear whether such specializations should have a value ctor, either.

Comment: cppreference is not the Standard, and copies of the final draft are easy to google online so why rely on cppreference if in doubt?  Anyway, saying something has a trivial default constructor isn't *necessarily* meant to imply it doesn't have any other non-default constructors... that's left unclear in the quoted text above.

Comment: Quoted from C++11 standard: *These specializations shall have standard layout, trivial default constructors, and trivial destructors. They shall each support aggregate initialization syntax.* It's still unclear whether they should have a value ctor.

Comment: Agreed - my comment's just saying the quoted text left the question open, but no particular reason to think this *"...a violation of the standard"*....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard mandates this some typedefs as per [atomics.types.generic]:

> There shall be named types corresponding to the integral specializations of atomic, as specified in Table 146,
>   and a named type `atomic_bool` corresponding to the specified `atomic<bool>`. Each named type is either a
>   `typedef` to the corresponding specialization or a base class of the corresponding specialization. If it is a base
>   class, it shall support the same member functions as the corresponding specialization.

In Table 146, we see that `atomic_int` is a typedef for `atomic<int>`. The *integral* specializations are defined in the same section as having:

```
template <> struct atomic<integral > {
    ...
    constexpr atomic(integral ) noexcept;
    ...
};
```

Substitute in `int` for *integral* and we have a `constexpr atomic_int(int )` constructor. Frankly, it'd be quite weird if you *couldn't* initialize an `atomic<T>` with a `T`...

Comment: The general version of the template has a value ctor does not imply a specialized version must have a value ctor also. You can always initialize `atomic<T>` with `T`. The question lies in the initialization method and syntax.

Comment: The standard declares full specializations for integral types with `template<> struct atomic<integral>;`, so what is in the primary template is irrelevant. However, the full specializations do have a `constexpr atomic(integral) noexcept;` constructor.

Comment: `atomic_int` is not necessarily a typedef, it may be a base class. *Each named type is a either typedef to the corresponding specialization or a base class of the corresponding specialization. If it is a base class, it shall support the same member functions as the corresponding specialization.*